# neo4j-admin import command not working in docker (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File 'import/nodes.csv' doesn't exist)

Tags: docker, neo4j

I am trying to load some csv data with the help of the `neo4j-admin import` command into neo4j running in docker.
First I ran the following docker run command:

```
docker run \
    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    --volume=C:/my_dir:/import \
    --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password \
    neo4j:5.11.0-community \
```

After the container was created and started I executed the import command in the docker desktop's neo4j container terminal.

```
bin/neo4j-admin database import full --id-type=INTEGER --nodes=NodeA=import/nodes.csv --nodes=NodeB=import/nodesB.csv --relationships=RELA=import/rels.csv --multiline-fields=true
```

But I get the following error:

```
Invalid value for option '--nodes' at index 0 ([<label>[:<label>]...=]<files>): Invalid nodes file: NodeA=import/nodes.csv (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File 'import/nodes.csv' doesn't exist)
```

I checked the import folder of the docker container and the folder is mounted and all the csv files are in it. So I do not know why the import is not working.

I have also installed the same neo4j version locally (windows), where I could successfully import the database with the same `neo4j-admin import` command mentioned above and the same csv files. But I could not make it work using docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the container, your command line needs to use the absolute address for the `import` directory. In your case, just insert '/' before the 3 `import`s:

```
bin/neo4j-admin database import full --id-type=INTEGER --nodes=NodeA=/import/nodes.csv --nodes=NodeB=/import/nodesB.csv --relationships=RELA=/import/rels.csv --multiline-fields=true
```

Comment: This has resolved my previous issue, but i could not import the database, because of the following error: `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /data/databases/neo4j already contains data, cannot do import here`

Comment: Then I deleted the container and tried to import the data alongside the docker run command:
`
docker run     --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687     --volume=C:/mydir/import:/import     --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password neo4j:5.11.0-community  bin/neo4j-admin database import full --id-type=INTEGER --nodes=NodeA=/import/nodes.csv --nodes=NobeB=/import/nodesB.csv --relationships=RELA=/import/relat.csv --multiline-fields=true
`

This has succesfully impoted the data, but now my container would not start. If I try to run the container from the docker desktop I get the prev error.

Comment: do you have any idea why this is so. It seems that when I run the container it wants to re-import the data (maybe because of my docker run command) and it fails to start.

Is this maybe because I am using the community edition in docker (this is written in the neo4j docs: [The neo4j-admin database import command: command-line tool useful for straightforward loading of large datasets. Works with Neo4j Desktop, Neo4j EE Docker image and local installations](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/data-import/csv-import/).)

Comment: You should create a new question for this issue.

Comment: yes, I already did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77239190/neo4j-docker-admin-import-cannot-start-container