# Neo4j docker - admin import - cannot start container

Tags: docker, neo4j

I want to run a neo4j database in docker and import data with the use of `neo4j-admin import` tool. I created a docker container with neo4j community edition with the following command:

```
    docker run --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    --volume=C:/mydir/import:/import \
    --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password \
    neo4j:5.11.0-community \
    bin/neo4j-admin database import full --id-type=INTEGER --nodes=NodeA=/import/nodesa.csv --nodes=NodeB=/import/nodesb.csv --relationships=RELA=/import/rels.csv --multiline-fields=true
```

This created the container and populated the database (the import finished succesfully):

```
IMPORT DONE in 13s 945ms.
Imported:
 75650 nodes
 95438 relationships
 255509 properties
Peak memory usage: 547.9MiB
```

But when I checked in the docker desktop the container was not running. I cannot strat the container, because it wants to re-import the data and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /data/databases/neo4j already contains data, cannot do import here
```

Why is this so and how can I run neo4j in docker and use the import tool. Or start the container after executing the above mentioned command.
I am using community edition of the database, is this maybe the problem; see: [The neo4j-admin database import command: command-line tool useful for straightforward loading of large datasets. Works with Neo4j Desktop, Neo4j EE Docker image and local installations.](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/data-import/csv-import/)
But I find it kind of odd that in the console I get the message that the database was imported.

Edit (logs from docker desktop after re-starting the container):

```
2023-10-05 19:47:47 Neo4j version: 5.11.0
2023-10-05 19:47:47 Importing the contents of these files into /data/databases/neo4j:
2023-10-05 19:47:47 Nodes:
2023-10-05 19:47:47   [NodeA]:
2023-10-05 19:47:47   /import/nodea.csv
2023-10-05 19:47:47 
2023-10-05 19:47:47   [NodeB]:
2023-10-05 19:47:47   /import/nodeb.csv
2023-10-05 19:47:47 
2023-10-05 19:47:47 Relationships:
2023-10-05 19:47:47   RELA:
2023-10-05 19:47:47   /import/rels.csv
2023-10-05 19:47:47 
2023-10-05 19:47:47 
2023-10-05 19:47:47 Available resources:
2023-10-05 19:47:47   Total machine memory: 11.70GiB
2023-10-05 19:47:48   Free machine memory: 10.06GiB
2023-10-05 19:47:48   Max heap memory : 2.601GiB
2023-10-05 19:47:48   Max worker threads: 8
2023-10-05 19:47:48   Configured max memory: 6.760GiB
2023-10-05 19:47:48   High parallel IO: true
2023-10-05 19:47:48 
2023-10-05 19:47:52 
2023-10-05 19:47:52 IMPORT FAILED in 0ms. 
2023-10-05 19:47:52 Data statistics is not available.
2023-10-05 19:47:52 Peak memory usage: 0B
2023-10-05 19:47:52 Database already exist. Re-run with `--overwrite-destination` to remove the database prior to import
2023-10-05 19:47:52 Caused by:/data/databases/neo4j already contains data, cannot do import here
2023-10-05 19:47:52 
2023-10-05 19:47:52 WARNING Import failed. The store files in /data/databases/neo4j are left as they are, although they are likely in an unusable state. Starting a database on these store files will likely fail or observe inconsistent records so start at your own risk or delete the store manually
2023-10-05 19:47:52 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /data/databases/neo4j already contains data, cannot do import here
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.importer.CsvImporter.andPrintError(CsvImporter.java:358)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.importer.CsvImporter.doImport(CsvImporter.java:268)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.importer.CsvImporter.doImport(CsvImporter.java:181)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.importer.ImportCommand$Base.doExecute(ImportCommand.java:405)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.importer.ImportCommand$Full.execute(ImportCommand.java:531)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:92)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:37)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool.execute(AdminTool.java:94)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool.main(AdminTool.java:82)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 Caused by: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /data/databases/neo4j already contains data, cannot do import here
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.store.BatchingNeoStores.assertDatabaseIsNonExistent(BatchingNeoStores.java:230)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.store.BatchingNeoStores.createNew(BatchingNeoStores.java:203)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:131)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 at org.neo4j.importer.CsvImporter.doImport(CsvImporter.java:264)
2023-10-05 19:47:52 ... 15 more
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: @cybersam added the logs from docker desktop, if anything else is needed please let me know.